# apache virtual server for single servername

Tags: apache-2.2

I am trying to run a single webserver, with one servername, on 2 ports. 80 and 443. Some areas of the website should be disallowed if it isn't using ssl on port 443.

The current implementation on the webserver uses a virtual server to differentiate b/w 443 and 80. I am wondering whether virtual servers make sense in this environment, I cannot find anyone talking about virtual servers where there is only one servername.

Does this make sense under ip-based virtual servers? Since it's only one ip address.

Thanks for shedding any light on this,
Nachum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a different VirtualHost (I believe this is what you mean when describing your current setup) for http and https is quite common.

To enforce https, you could use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://yourserver.com$1 [R,L]
```

This can of course be modified to only apply to some URLs:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/secure-area(.*) https://yourserver.com/secure-area$1 [R,L]
```

These should be placed in your :80 VirtualHost (http) to prevent redirect loops.

Alternatively, you could also use a RewriteCond condition to restrict the rule to non-https traffic:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/secure-area(.*) https://yourserver.com/secure-area$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You still need to define two different `<VirtualHost>` blocks for the different ports, because the SSL directives need to be present for port 443 and absent for port 80.

It sounds like you have some additional divergence between your 80 and 443 configurations anyway with the added access controls - can you clarify what your concern is with having the configuration in two different `<VirtualHost>` blocks for your two different listening ports?

Comment: I don't have an issue with different virtual hosts, but i could not find any articles online about using virtual hosts for a single server (servername). That's why I asked.

Comment: @nachum See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ssl/ssl_faq.html#parallel - `You can either run two separate server instances bound to these ports, or use Apache's elegant virtual hosting facility to create two virtual servers, both served by the same instance of Apache - one responding over HTTP to requests on port 80, and the other responding over HTTPS to requests on port 443.`